# What is this strange gateway?

Tags: path-of-exile

I encountered this gateway in the Western Forest that I don't remember seeing before. I can't interact with it, but I can walk right through the opening.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a start/end point for the Transportation syndicate encounter, nothing you can interact with. You will also see plenty of those in the transportation safehouse where you can see the trains enter and exit them.